# Deluge: submitting a translation MO file

Tags: locale, deluge

I have updated one of the MO localisation files. How and where do I submit the file?

Polish (PL) language

Answer (score 1):

From Deluge [translation wiki](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Development/Translation):

"To help translate Deluge please register at the Launchpad [​translation site](https://translations.launchpad.net/deluge/)"

You can upload a Polish translation file in the PO format if you are a member of the [Ubuntu Polish Translators team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-pl). So if you aren't a member you may want to apply to join, or else you can ask a member to upload it for you.